# Wrong form is being displayed in a Django project

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django project I created. This django project is split into two apps, the user and common. I have a method in the user app that allows the user to submit a form which will create a new Django user. Once the form is submitted and process I want to redirect the user to the testing page in the common app and display a html template that says testing page. Everything is working, the form is being processed and the redirect is occuring. I know this because the url changed to the expected url which will display the html testing page. For some reason, even though the url is transfering to the correct one, the html template being displayed is actually the signup form html template not the correct template.

Here is the code from the common app:

views.py

```
# testing method
def test(request):
    return render(request, 'common/test.html')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/$', views.test, name='test'),
]
```

test.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block standard %}

    <p>testing page</p>

{% endblock %}
```

here is the redirect from the users app:

this is in the signup def after the user has been created

```
return redirect('test')
```

here is the entire signup method:

```
# have a user signup and create his account
def Signup(request):
    # check to see if form is submitted
    if request.method == "POST":
        # grab the form and information
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        # validating form
        if form.is_valid():
            # grab the form content
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            username = cd['username']
            password = cd['password']
            verify = cd['verify']
            email = cd['email']
            # check if passwords match
            if password == verify:
                # create safe passwords
                secure_password = make_password(password)
                # save username in sessions
                # request.session['username'] = username
                return redirect('test')
            else:
                # redirec to original forms
                message = "Passwords did not match"
                # users form
                form = SignupForm()
                # everything required for the template
                parameters = {
                    'message':message,
                    'form':form,
                }
                # display html template
                return render(request, 'user/Signup.html', parameters)
    else:
        # the signing up form
        form = SignupForm()
        message = "Please fill out the entire form"
        # everything that needs to be passed to html template
        parameters = {
            'form':form,
            'message':message,
        }
        # render the template
        return render(request, 'user/Signup.html', parameters)
```

Comment: can provide code for signup method ?

Comment: added signup method @navyad

Comment: I ran a print line in the test def within the common method that did not print. which means that it did not read the return redner statement in the test method... but the url has changed to common/test which is supposed to display the test page template. where is this lack of communication comming from between the url and view

Comment: where is return `redirect('test')` in signup method ?

Comment: after `if password == verify:` could it be the if statement is not valid.... but it should be valid... @navyad if so then why is the url at the top changing

Comment: I tried just running the test page right from url and the `commong/test/` is displaying the signup form not the test page....

Comment: i am assuming that `password == verify` is failing. Can you print cd ?

Comment: it was the order of the urls in the settings page of the project....